# How to bypass argparse multi-word argument quotations?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a bubble.py script with an argparse set-up as below. There is only one positional argument `'text'` and few other optional arguments (omitted for simplicity).

bubble.py

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Create pixel art bubble speech image")
parser.add_argument('text', type=str, help="Text inside the bubble speech")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I ran the command `bubble.py hello` the program works just fine.
When I ran the command `bubble.py "hello world"` the program works fine as well.
But I want to run the command `bubble.py hello world` (without the quotations). Is it possible? If so, how?

Also asking if this would work on any operating system.

Comment: The operating system and python split that line into `['bubble.py', 'hello', 'world']`.  That is `sys.argv` is a list of 3 strings.  That split has nothing to do with `argparse`.  You could specify `nargs='+'` to accept both strings, but it will still be 2 strings, not one with a space.

Comment: Not the operating system: the command shell used to execute the script.

Comment: There will almost certainly be other reasons you'll need to escape characters other than spaces, so there's little reason to complicate your Python code to eliminate just one reason to use quotes.

Comment: Hmm, it seems it is as what chepner suggested. It works mostly fine on windows, but gives varying errors on mac mostly when text involves special characters such as punctuations.